# XML parsing of large amount of data

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Which is the optimal way of XML parsing(XML may be of large amount of data) in php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [XML and PHP 5 in Devzone](http://devzone.zend.com/article/2387) for a good introduction.

Basically, if you need to process large volumes of XML files, you will want to use a pull parser, like XMLReader or XMLParser to prevent running into memory issues. Parser like DOM or SimpleXML will read the whole files into memory before you can process them.

Answer (score 0):

one of the most common ways is [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). it's pretty easy to use and fast.

Comment: SimpleXML is not the best solution, with large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

i've used [SAXY XML parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxy-xmlparser/) in the past. try it.

Comment: does this have any advantage over PHP's native extensions?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a way to parse XML data that is valid for PHP4 too, then you can use the [XML parser](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php), or [DOM XML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.domxml.php) (which is a PHP4 only extensions); if you need a solution for PHP5, then you can use [DOM](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), or [XMLReader](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php).

It depends from your needs.