# Parsing BIG XML in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, xml-parsing

I need to parse an XML that is big. f.ex 100mb (it can be even more).

For Example:
Xml looks like this:

```
<notes>
  <note>
    <id>cdsds32da435-wufdhah</id>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
  </note>


 x 1000000 different notes(or even more)

</notes>
```

Each note has un unique ID. When I Parse an XML, I need to first find if note by specific ID exists in DB if no than INSERT it.

The problem is in Performance(it takes 2 hours). I try to take all ids from the DB (but is also big) with one SELECT, so I dont ask DB each time and I have them in PHP Array (Memory).

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM 'notes'";
...
$ids = Array with all ids
```

I 've also parsed an XML with xml_parser in a loop:

```
while($data = fread($Xml, '512')) {
    xml_parse($xmlParser, $data);
}
```

I think that parse an XML with simple_xml_parser may generate a too big variable for PHP to handle it.

And than when I have a note ID I check if it exists in $ids:

```
if (array_search($note->id, $ids) === FALSE) {
    //than insert it
}
```

But it takes too long. So I found that PHP comes with special Arrays called Juddy Arrays  http://php.net/manual/en/book.judy.php but I don't know exactly if they are for this - I mean for quick parse BIG Arrays.

I think also with Memcached, to store the ids from DB in many variables, but I want to find a proper solution.

In DB table there are also indexes, to speed up the process. The XML grows every week :) and it conatins every time all notes from the last XML plus new notes.

QUESTION?
How to fast parse BIG ARRAYS in PHP? Are Judy Arrays for this? And storing all ids from DB in a variable is a good solution? - it can be to big for PHP in one time.

Comment: SimpleXML would be fine with this, so long as you have enough memory free. If your database queries are just to detect duplicate IDs in the XML, then using SimpleXML means you don't need to access your database at all. Just configure enough RAM for PHP `:)`

Comment: You could also use some simple file operations to split up a huge XML document into several manageable ones. If your XML file is constantly growing, you will have to do something about that one day. Maybe have one XML file per month?

Comment: No, xml_parse() is exactly what you need because, it just reads the buffer and you can clean it after that. It looks like you're making an associative array for the lookup, use the language construct `isset()` for faster checks, like `if (isset($ids[$note->id]))`. I am not sure if this really helps you with getting faster. Maybe you should have a look into [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/splfixedarray).

Comment: Can you make assumptions about the order of the elements within a <note> element? I.e. is there some schema that defines the order/sequence of elements? Or do you just happen to know that <id> is always the first child of <note>? Or are the elements in arbitrary order?

Comment: The order can be different, but ID is always in one note.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: I.e. there can be a `<note><from>..</from><to>..</to><id>..</id>...</note>` and/or a `<note><id>..</id><to>..</to><from>..</from>...</note>` in the same document? My question targets whether or not you can dumb down the script to only search for <id> elements without node expansion or further variables (except for one status flag). Btw: did you profile/time your script to find out which component is the bottleneck (disk access, the core xml parser, your script code handling the parser data, the connection to mysql, your table definition, ...)?

Comment: The bottleneck is SELECT id, because in DB there is dozens of IDS. So I store them all in one variable to speed up proccess from doing SELECT each time, but is huge for PHP memory. Status flag for ID can't be done, because the order can be different, so i need to remember values before i find ID in node.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML parsing of large amount of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387371/xml-parsing-of-large-amount-of-data)

Answer (score 1):

When I parsed [DMOZ database](http://rdf.dmoz.org/)
(2G xml) I have been used Java solutions (SAX parser). First I was need to transfer a very big array of data from XML (RDF format) into MySQL database. My PHP solution performed this task over 6 hours. But Java solution was made similar task after 15 min. So I can tell you: try to use Java solution based on SAX parser.

Comment: PHP has a [SAX like XML parsers](http://php.net/manual/book.xml.php) as well and there is also [libxml based XML Reader](http://php.net/manual/book.xmlreader.php). Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to find if the item exists in the DB before inserting it? You can just tell the DB to 'insert it if it does not exist': put a unique key on the ID and use [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html).

Comment: Yes, I need, because it INSERTS new note and ALSO creates other rows in different TABLES, when note is new.